# Unterminated tag in JSP after after upgrading project

Tags: jsp, tomcat, ant, wildfly

I recently upgraded my java app to java 1.8, Wildfly14, tomcat-8.0.21, ant-1.9.0 from java1.5, JBoss 4.2, tomcat-6.0.18, ant-1.7.1. And i started to see following errors.

*build.xml:425: The following error occurred while executing this line:
build.xml:192: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: file:H:/controlpanel.jsp (line: 1082, column: 2) Unterminated <% tag*

When i looked at the corresponding line (i.e. below), there doesnt seem to be any problem with the code.

```
<% }    // signing popup else %>
```

Seems like the comments are not getting validated. If i remove above above line with following it works.

```
<% } %>
```

Now problem is, its a big enterprise app. Its not possible to fix every file. I have looked through possible solutions but didnt fix my problem yet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my project specific issue. Following ant call was the culprit:-

```
    <target name="strip_whitespaces" if="env.PERL_HOME">
        <exec executable="${env.PERL_HOME}\bin\perl">
            <arg line="strip.pl css:js:jsp:inc:html ${dir}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
    <antcall target="strip_whitespaces">
        <param name="dir" value="${build}/webapp"/>
    </antcall>
```

strip.pl was striping whitespace and comments from the jsp files. And thus resulting in vague compilation errors. Once i removed this antcall, jsp compiled just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://regex101.com/r/5c3Dbd/1) to replace all comments with end tags and replace with newline before the end tags:

```
\/\/([^%]+)%>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this wouldnt solve the problem, as its a huge app. I am trying to find a way if there is a configuration that can be changed to make it work.

Comment: @HiteshThakur it is just replace all